# How do I quote poetry, with newlines intact?

Tags: support, markdown

A number of mythological sources are written in verse, and maintaining lines is usually ideal.  You can get a new line by adding an extra line between each line of the quote, but this produces an awful lot of extra white space.  Taking a random example from the Poetic Edda:

```
> Counsel me, Frigg, for I long to fare,

> And Vafthruthnir fain would find;

> fit wisdom old with the giant wise

> Myself would I seek to match.
```

Results in:

> Counsel me, Frigg, for I long to fare,
>
> And Vafthruthnir fain would find;
>
> fit wisdom old with the giant wise
>
> Myself would I seek to match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looked at some posts on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), and you can preserve a newline by adding two spaces at the end of the line:

```
> Counsel me, Frigg, for I long to fare,  
And Vafthruthnir fain would find;  
fit wisdom old with the giant wise  
Myself would I seek to match.
```

Which results in:

> Counsel me, Frigg, for I long to fare,
>   And Vafthruthnir fain would find;
>   fit wisdom old with the giant wise
>   Myself would I seek to match.

Which seems much nicer.  Sorry if this is common knowledge, but I've been annoyed by it more than once before, and it was news to me.

Comment: I actually just discovered this nuisance today, and assumed it was unsolvable. Thanks for pointing out the workaround.

Comment: I discovered this by editing one of @Yannis posts

Comment: Based on my pretty extensive SE participation, this is not exactly common knowledge. Even on SFF.SE where quoting sources - e.g. show transcripts - is a frequent occsion) people don't often know this trick.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the double space at the end of a line to add a line break in the rendering, you can also use the html "non-breaking space" character `&nbsp;` to add in the extra spaces for the lines that often have them.

This:

```
> Counsel me, Frigg, for I long to fare,  
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; And Vafthruthnir fain would find;  
&nbsp; fit wisdom old with the giant wise  
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Myself would I seek to match.
```

Becomes this:

> Counsel me, Frigg, for I long to fare,
>         And Vafthruthnir fain would find;
>     fit wisdom old with the giant wise
>         Myself would I seek to match.

It's very hard to read it in the markdown code, but it does make the poetry very pretty.

Comment: To make it easy to read it in markdown, perhaps adding a couple extra spaces after all the NBSPs may help

Comment: @DVK Yes, that does optimize things and makes it easier to read.